Terraform: Task definition cannot be deregistered because it is in the process of being deleted
I'm pretty stumped with this issue while using Terraform to update some AWS infra. I am trying to apply a change to some environment variables, that will result in the task definition of one of my ecs services being updated. When running terraform apply, I am getting the below error:
module.<redacted>.aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_def: Destroying... [id=<redacted>]
╷
│ Error: ClientException: The task definition could not be deregistered because it is in the process of being deleted.
│ 
│ 
╵

This has been happening consistently for about 2 days now. I have tried manually deregistering the task definition from the AWS console, which hasn't helped. I have also reduced my changes to the most simple update possible, basically setting a new env var: "test"= "test", to (attempt to) iron out anything in my code that could be the cause.
Terraform info:
Terraform v1.8.3
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.75.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.2.1

Does anyone have any suggestions I might be able to try?
Any help greatly appreciated

That is a very old version of the AWS provider, and that is also probably root cause. Have you tried updating?

Thanks @Matthew Schuchard. It turned out to be a strange conflict which I can't quite explain, but I managed to find a fix for my issue. I will have a look at updating the provider anyway, thank you.

After reading some resources such as:
this and this
I found that the current task definition being used by my service was in a state of DELETE_IN_PROGRESS. I'm not sure what caused it to get placed in that state, but the fact that the service was still running meant that the task def was being kept alive. The solution was to create a new task definition revision manually, update the service to use this new definition, and then restart the service. About 10 minutes after doing this, AWS managed to delete the old(now unused) task def. Then, using the method in the answer here, I needed to wipe my local state for that resource and I could then terraform apply to get my changes in.
